# Does Elizabeth Hempstock have a Jungle Book parallel

Tags: neil-gaiman, the-graveyard-book, the-jungle-book

*The Graveyard Book* is an parallel to *The Jungle Book*.

Many of the Major characters have a direct parallel. For example:

- Bod : Mowgli
- Silas : Bagheera
- Miss Lupescu : Baloo
- The Owens : Mother/Father Wolf

Elizabeth Hempstock is a fairly major character, however she seems to be original with no obvious parallel.

**Is there a character in one of the Mowgli stories who is an equivalent to her?**

(I only know the first Jungle Book and can't see one, and know there are other stories out there which may contain other parallels).

Answer (score 6):

[The TVTropes entry](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Literature/TheGraveyardBook) has, under "Expy":

> - Mowgli: Nobody Owens.
> - Mother and Father Wolf: The Owens
> - Bagheera: Silas
> - Baloo: Miss Lupescu
> - Shere Khan: Jack
> - The Dholes: The Jacks of All Trades
> - The White Cobra: The Sleer
> - Bandar-Log: Ghoul-folk
> - Chil the Kite: Night-Gaunt
> - **Kaa: Elizabeth Hempstock**
> - Akela: The Lady on the Grey

I'm not familiar with *The Graveyard Book*, but I'd hazard that they're banking on how both Hempstock and [Kaa](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kaa) are mentor figures to the main character who are otherwise shunned for their alien nature (Kaa for being a snake who can bewitch people, Hempstock for being an unshriven witch).

Comment: I have seen Kaa mentioned. Seems a less obvious fit. There was a bit of a romantic tension between Liz and Bod.

Comment: "With Kaa's help Mowgli tricks the dholes into attacking prematurely. Kaa takes no part in the resulting battle (obliquely citing his loyalty to the boy rather than to the wolves, who often caused Mowgli grief) but Mowgli and the wolves finally kill all the dholes, though not without grievous losses." [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kaa).  Seems like a tight fit to Elizabeth Hempstock to me.  The Hepstock character appears over and over in Gaiman's stories (e.g. "The Ocean at the End of the Lane", "Neverwhere").