# What is Neil Gaiman's "enormous debt" to The Jungle Book that he mentions in the acknowledgments in The Graveyard Book?

Tags: the-graveyard-book, the-jungle-book

The acknowledgments in *The Graveyard Book* mention an "enormous debt" to Rudyard Kipling’s *[The Jungle Book](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Jungle_Book)*.  What does Gaiman mean by this?

Comment: One thing he probably means is he thinks if you enjoy *The Graveyard Book* then you should also read *The Jungle Book*.

Answer (score 56):

The *entire book* is sort of a re-telling of *The Jungle Book* (hence the analogous name, *The Graveyard Book*) as a gothic urban fantasy.

From the very beginning, when Bod is brutally separated from his family and has to get acceptance from a council in order to be fostered/adopted into a new living arrangement, it follows the general outline of *The Jungle Book*. There is a silky, smooth teacher and also a furry, rougher teacher, there are many mini-vignettes (such as the kidnapping — and means of escape — on the way to Ghûlheim) that model corresponding scenes in *The Jungle Book*, and also entities like the Sleer that have a clear analog in the original.

Once a reader has cottoned on, it's quite enjoyable to read the two and compare them, to see Gaiman's rendition of/homage to what he clearly respects as a masterwork.

Comment: FWIW, we had [a question discussing where Elizabeth Hempstock fits in](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/147255/does-elizabeth-hempstock-have-a-jungle-book-parallel)